# Can't connect to MySQL docker container launched via ansible

Tags: mysql, docker, ansible

I get an "Access denied" error trying to connect to the MySQL Docker container that I start through my ansible script. If I create the container with the Docker CLI tool, everything works. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the environment variables.

### This works

```
$ docker run --name database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hunter2 -d mysql:5.7

$ mysql -h $CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS -u root -phunter2
$ mysql>
```

### This is broken

**playbook.yml**

```
- name: Start new MySQL container                                                  
  docker:                                                                          
    name: database                                                                   
    image: mysql:5.7                                               
    state: running                                                                 
    env:                                                                           
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hunter2
```

Then the connection fails:

```
$ mysql -h $CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS -u root -phunter2

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'$CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS' (using password: YES)
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `env` definition for the [docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) should be a dict object, not a string

```
env:                                                                           
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: hunter2
```

Comment: Sometimes a pair of fresh eyes is all you need. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

After some time I found that ansible does not play well with Docker. I've been moving some infraestructure from ansible to Docker, and keeping some legacy code like adding users to mysql or dumping dbs didn't work from Ansible.

The solution is to use shell instead:

```
- name: Drop/delete mysql table {{ mysql_table }}
  shell: mysqladmin -h 127.0.0.1 -p{{ mysql_password }} -u{{ mysql_user }} drop {{ mysql_table }} -f
  # If it fails it means db was already deleted, so continue.
  ignore_errors: True
  tags:
    - mysql
    - mysql_rebuild_db
    - mysql_rebuild_db_quick

- name: Add mysql table {{ mysql_table }}
  shell: mysqladmin -h 127.0.0.1 -p{{ mysql_password }} -u{{ mysql_user }}     create {{ mysql_table }} -f
  tags:
    - mysql
    - mysql_rebuild_db
    - mysql_rebuild_db_quick

- name: Create mysql user {{ mysql_user }} in {{ mysql_table }}
  shell: echo "CREATE USER {{ mysql_user }}@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '{{ mysql_password }}';" | mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -proot -uroot
  # The user may already exists in a previous run
  ignore_errors: True
  tags:
    - mysql
    - mysql_rebuild_db
    - mysql_rebuild_db_quick
```

Comment: said that, that has probably been fixed in ansible 2.0: http://blog.oddbit.com/2015/10/13/ansible-20-the-docker-connection-driver/